# issue in jumping from one activity(layout) to another activity

Tags: android, android-button

hi just getting head ache. unable to find issue. all buttons are working properly and jumping properly from one activity to another but "button About" is not working properly. it must jump to "about activity" ... kindly check the code for issue... "About button" having problem has a comment and is in the last... thanks and regards

activity having about button

```
package com.example.routetracker;



import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Select_destination extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button close,main,about,texila,aslam_market,royal_son,comsat;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_destination);

    mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.selectdestination);


            mPlayer.start();
            texila=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_texila);
            texila.setOnClickListener(this);
            aslam_market=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_aslam_market);
            aslam_market.setOnClickListener(this);
            royal_son=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_royal_son);
            royal_son.setOnClickListener(this);
            comsat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_comsat_wah);
            comsat.setOnClickListener(this);
            main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
            main.setOnClickListener(this);
            about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
            about.setOnClickListener(this);
            close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
            close.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_texila:
        mPlayer.stop();

        Intent i=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        i.putExtra("place", "1");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_aslam_market:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent j=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        j.putExtra("place", "2");
        startActivity(j);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_royal_son:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent k=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        k.putExtra("place", "3");
        startActivity(k);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_comsat_wah:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent l=new Intent(Select_destination.this,Start_tracking.class);
        l.putExtra("place", "4");
        startActivity(l);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_main:
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent o=new Intent(Select_destination.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(o);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_about:  // for this button i have problem
        mPlayer.stop();
        Intent e=new Intent(Select_destination.this,About.class);
        startActivity(e);
        break;



    case R.id.btn_close:
        mPlayer.stop();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}


}
```

About Activity Code

```
package com.example.routetracker;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class About extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button close,main;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    main=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
    main.setOnClickListener(this);

    close=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
    close.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_main:
        Intent o=new Intent(About.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(o);
        break;

    case R.id.btn_close:
        System.exit(1);
        break;


    }


}
```

}

XML code for about button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_about"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_main"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_main"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_main"
    android:text="About" />
```

Comment: See a doctor.. or else post your logcat/stacktrace...

Comment: What's the exception / error you're getting? Is your about activity registered in the manifest file?

Comment: hey man you rocks...
that was actually issue 
thanks alot...
Love you.... :P